# Can I have part of my program optimized for speed while debugging the rest in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I'm trying to debug a program, but initializing (loading data) takes very long time in Debug mode (more than 10 minutes) where as it takes milliseconds in release mode.

Is there an easy way to compile the unimportant cpp file in Release mode, while the rest of the program in Debug mode?
I've tried changing the properties of the cpp file from Optimization `Disabled (/Od)` to `Maximize Speed (/O2)` but then I get this error `1>cl : Command line error D8016: '/O2' and '/RTC1' command-line options are incompatible`

Comment: Having a mix of unoptimized and optimized dlls in unmanaged code is dangerous. Mainly because the offset of data objects change due to checks that compiler puts in unoptimized dlls for bufer overruns.

Comment: Maybe debug mode does some logging that can be disabled?

Comment: what's initializing/loading data? One day I had a case where starting debugging session would take a long time and it turned out that I had _NT_SYMBOL_PATH environment variable set which caused to load symbols for **all** dlls. First time was the worst since it went to MSFT symbol server and downloaded tons of pdbs. After that it was quicker but it still would take a few minutes because loading pdbs is not very fast.

Comment: Loading data means parsing big csv files; this takes up all the time. I've now cut up the files so debugging is feasable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. There's nothing stopping you from switching some projects to release mode and others to debug, assuming you actually have different projects and they produce dynamically linked libraries (dlls). Not too sure if this works with statically linked libraries too.

It might be also nice to know that you can debug your optimized-for-speed build by turning on debug symbols in the linking phase (project->properties->linker->debuggin->"Generate debug info":"optimize for debugging". It will not show all variables and doesn't let you jump into inlined functions but it does let you debug slow programs.